# Highlight Excel Cells if there is not text in one of two columns

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have tried looking for an answer all day, and have tried several different equations that I thought should work, but haven't found anything that does.

I have two columns E & F.  They will either be blank, because the product hasn't been mailed or picked up, or they will have a date in one, depending on if it was mailed out or picked up by the customer.  I am looking for an equation that will highlight cells only if there is no date in either column.

I have tried many equations, and continue to have cells highlighted if there is a date in the other column.  I have tried different IF, AND, OR functions, but then nothing is highlighted for some reason.  I have not tried TRUE FALSE statements because I don't quite understand them.

My most recent attempt is:  =AND(ISNOTBLANK($E$2:$E$550), (ISNOTBLANK($F$2:$F$550)))
I thought this would highlight the cells that do not have a date in either column, but that is not the case.

I will upload screenshots if anyone would like clarification.  I am quickly losing my mind at this, so thank you in advance so much!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a formula that is valid for the **first row** of the data only.....and use the full range as the "applies to" range in conditional formatting, so use this formula

`=COUNT($E2:$F2)=0`

Keep the $ signs exactly as shown

You can set the "applies to" range to the range you want formatted, e.g. `$E$2:$F$500`

...and excel automatically implicitly adjusts the formula for each row

`COUNT` function counts numbers....and in Excel a date is just a formatted number so when the count is zero that means you have no dates